# Can we have multiple effect in Azure Policy

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I have created a policy which will enable Azure Hybrid Benefit for Windows Servers, Client & SQL. We have multiple subscriptions created based on prod and sandbox. What i'm looking for is, If the subscription is belongs to prod then it should do audit and for others it should do Append. So i think it should have kind of if else condition or where condition, but as i checked i don't see any reference article or any possibble solutions to achieve the same. Can someone guide me how to acheive the same. Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Logan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider setting up an [Azure Management Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview) hierarchy with the first level below the Root MG broken out into Prod and Sandbox.  From there, you can [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/scope) different Azure Policies (one for Audit, the other for Append) depending on the Management Group the subscription falls under.

[image]

Comment: yeah even i was planned to go for the mgmt group based. But then we'll be having too many policies ex dev, uat, prod, sandbox and managebility and additions are difficult to edit each and every policies. Is there any other alternate way include it in policy itself?

Comment: you could do some value operator conditions but honestly I think it would be a nightmare to troubleshoot.  I think it is cleaner to have separate policy definition. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/pattern-value-operator

Comment: True and i think afaik it's not possible to have two effects in single policy. So i'll have to go with individual policies based on the management group. Thank you for sharing!